# iOS - Launch “Workplace Chat by Facebook” Application from other application

Tags: ios, facebook, chat, url-scheme, facebook-workplace

I would like to open the “Workplace Chat by Facebook” application ( https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workplace-chat-by-facebook/id958124798?mt=8 ) via URL like the Facebook app does.

For example: When I try to open "fb://page/" inside my custom application, it will launch the Facebook app from my device (if installed).

So I would like to know the URL schemes of the Workplace Chat application.